# PhpStorm Project view colors

Tags: phpstorm, color-scheme

As you can see in the attached image, when I use the Darcula theme the files in the project browser's name color is almost exactly the same as the background, making navigation a nightmare.

I would prefer to stick with the Darcula theme for my IDE (not just the editor) - could someone help me find the setting that adjusts these colors?

[image]

Comment: There must be something wrong with your settings -- if you use Darcula (both Color Schema for editor and GUI Theme) all colors are more than readable. Right now it's possible that you are using custom Color Schema .. which is not meant to be used with dark GUI Theme. Try setting up both to Darcula again (e.g. switch to Default first and then back to Darcula)

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the tip - resetting to default alone didn't help, but resetting to default and then restarting php storm with default colors, and THEN swapping to Darcula did the trick :)